# Анализ функции и предложения по улучшению

Tags: activerecord, php, codeigniter

Доброго времени суток.
Если не сложно посмотрите пожалуйста данную функцию и скажите что я сделал в ней не правильно, что можно использовать а что можно улучшить.
Буду очень благодарен.
Заранее прошу извинение за упоротость рубит по страшному...
Данная функция удаляет элементы из базы

```
    public function select_deleteAll($type)//Удаление выбранных продуктов
{ //$type - содержит ключ для массива с данными которого будем работать
    $res_varchar = 0; //Резервная переменная что бы нотисы не вылетали
    $data = array(); //Тоже самое что и выше но только массив 
    $data_my = array( //В этом массиве находятся все данные с которыми мы будем работать
        'warehouse' => array('dbs' => 'myshop_warehouse', 'cmd' => 'warehouse_delete'),
        //warehouse - ключ по которому будут выдираться данные
        //dbs - название базы данных с которой будем работать
        //cmd - ниже у нас идет подключение шаблона а cmd указывает какой блок с сообщениями задействовать
        'brand' => array('dbs' => 'myshop_brands', 'cmd' => 'brands_delete'),
        'product' => array(
            'dbs' => 'myshop_products',
            'cmd' => 'product_delete',
            'cycle' => array( //Указывает что у нас будет задействован цикл на вложеные массивы
                array(
                    'spec_type' => 'properties_data', // Это название основного ключа из которого мы будем выдирать dbs
                    'spec_type_data' => 'delete', //тип действий: update - обновление данных, delete - удаление данных, update_delete - (удаление и обновление) или (обновление или удаление)
                    'first' => 'item_id', // обычно тут мы указываем поле с которым будем работать
                ),

                ),
            ),

        'category' => array( //Это ключ для работы с таблицей myshop_category
            'dbs' => 'myshop_category',
            'cmd' => 'category_delete',
            'cycle' => array(
                array( //В этом блоке мы будем работать с таблицей myshop_products 
                    'spec_type' => 'product', //Тут мы указываем что будем работать с данными массива у которого ключ product
                    'spec_type_data' => 'update', //myshop_products мы будем обновлять
                    'first' => 'category_id', //И обновим мы поле category_id
                    'first_data' => '0', //Вот тут обычно находится значение на которое нужно обновить, в данном случае обновим поле category_id на значение 0
                ),

                array(
                    'spec_type' => array('update' => 'properties', 'delete' => 'properties_data'), //Тут мы указываем что будем работать с 2мя базами это myshop_properties и myshop_properties_data
                    //Сначала мы обновим таблицу myshop_properties а потом удалим нужные данные из таблицы myshop_properties_data
                    'spec_type_data' => 'update_delete', //Тут мы указываем что будем обновлять и удалять данные
                    'first' => 'category', // указываем что в myshop_properties мы будем обновлять поле category
                    'second' => 'id', //тут мы указываем из какого поля получать данные в таблице myshop_properties для того что бы потом удалить по id данные из myshop_properties_data 
                    'secod_data' => 'properties_id', //А вот тут мы указываем что значение id из myshop_properties соответствует properties_id из myshop_properties_data
                ),

                ),
            ),

        'banner' => array('dbs' => 'myshop_banners', 'cmd' => 'banner_delete'),
        'delivery' => array('dbs' => 'myshop_delivery', 'cmd' => 'delivery_delete'),
        'payment' => array('dbs' => 'myshop_payment', 'cmd' => 'payment_delete'),
        'properties' => array('dbs' => 'myshop_properties', 'cmd' => 'properties_delete'),
        'properties_data' => array('dbs' => 'myshop_properties_data', 'cmd' => 'properties_data_delete'),

    );
    if (sizeof($data_my[$type]) < 2) return false; // Сразу проверяем что в массиве с данными минимум 2 ключа, иначе уходим
    $data[$data_my[$type]['cmd']] = true; //Заранее активируем блок с сообщениями
    $ids = $this->input->post('ids'); //А вот тут у нас массив с id элементов которые мы будем использовать
    foreach ($ids as $id) //Запускаем цикл и обрабатываем все id
    {
        if ($id > 0) //Мало ли что, пустые значения заноситься не будут а вот 0 может влезть, по этому проверяем
        {
            $this->db->where('id', $id); //Все таблицы имеют поле id
            $this->db->delete($data_my[$type]['dbs']); //Тут мы используем наш массив и получаем базу данных из которой мы удалим полученный из цикла ID объекта
            $data['updated'] = true; //Допустим удаление прошло успешно и в выбранном блоке выведется сообщение о том что все хорошо
            if (isset($data_my[$type]['cycle'])) // Тут мы проверяем существует ли ключ cycle, если да, тот помимо стандартного удаления мы будем делать что то еще
            {
                foreach ($data_my[$type]['cycle'] as $prop) //Запускаем цикл и собираем инфу из блоков в cycle
                {//для примера давайте поработаем с ключом 'category'
                    if ($prop['spec_type_data'] == 'update')// Если в $data_my['category']['cycle']['spec_type_data'] - передается значение update, значит будем что то обновлять (с)кэп
                    {
                        $data_sync = array(
                            $prop['first'] => $prop['first_data'], //ключ first несет в себе значение category_id а first_data 0 таким образом мы будем обновлять category_id на 0
                        );
                        $this->db->where($prop['first'], $id);// WHERE category_id = $id
                        $sync = $data_my[$prop['spec_type']]['dbs']; //Тут мы получаем название базы с которой работаем в данном случае myshop_products  вот так выглядит не сокращенный вызов $data_my[ ['category']['cycle']['spec_type'] ]['dbs']
                        $this->db->update($sync, $data_sync); //обновляем
                    }

                    if ($prop['spec_type_data'] == 'delete')
                    {//тут тоже самое что и сверху но в category мы не используем delete
                        $this->db->where($prop['first'], $id);
                        $db_sync = $data_my[$prop['spec_type']]['dbs'];
                        $this->db->delete($db_sync);
                    }

                    if ($prop['spec_type_data'] === 'update_delete') //тут мы будем работать с (удалением и обновлением) или (удалением или обновлением)
                    {
                        if (isset($prop['spec_type']['update'])) //запрашиваем есть ли у нас массив $data_my['category']['cycle']['spec_type']['update'] если нет, то и делать тут нечего 
                        {
                            $this->db->like($prop['first'], $id.',', 'both'); //first - несет в себе поле category и в нем данные в таком виде: 66,32,14 - т.е id категорий к которым привязана строка
                            $sync = $data_my[$prop['spec_type']['update']]['dbs']; //Получаем базу с которой будем работать полный запрос выглядит так: $data_my[$data_my['category']['cycle']['spec_type']['update'] ]['dbs']
                            $sync = $this->db->get($sync)->result();//Ищем есть ли у нас совпадения по запросу, если нет то и делать нечего не надо
                            //
                            foreach ($sync as $db_sync) //Если что то есть то запускаем цикл
                            {
                                $to_db = preg_replace('@'.$id.',@', '', $db_sync->$prop['first']);// first - у нас содержит поле category в котором данные выглядят вот так: 2,66,9 
                                $res_varchar = $db_sync->$prop['second']; //Сразу же заносим id строки в переменную т.к если будем еще работать и с удалением нам это понадобиться 
                                if (isset($prop['spec_type']['delete'])) //Проверяем есть ли массив с ключом delete если есть, значит надо что то удалять
                                {
                                    $this->db->where($prop['secod_data'], $res_varchar); //second_data - содержит поле properties_id в базе myshop_properties_data таким образом id из myshop_properties == properties_id из myshop_properties_data
                                    $sql = $data_my[$prop['spec_type']['delete']]['dbs'];
                                    $this->db->delete($sql);//Если есть значения то удаляем
                                }
                                $data_sync = array($prop['first'] => $to_db);//Теперь опять работаем с update...в $to_db у нас содержится отредактированная информация без не нужных нам id
                                $this->db->where($prop['second'], $res_varchar);
                                $sql = $data_my[$prop['spec_type']['update']]['dbs'];
                                if (strlen($to_db) > 1) //Если в $to_db символов больше чем 1 то обновляем, иначе просто удаляем строку это может быть если у нас было например в поле category 66, а нам как раз и нужно было исключить 66, из объекта 
                                {
                                    $this->db->update($sql, $data_sync);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $this->db->delete($sql);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->template->add_array($data);
    $this->ajax_tpl('ajax');
}
```

Comment: перегружено комментами - читать невозможно

Comment: Извините, хотел как лучше))
http://pastebin.com/3FWZFhrm - без комментариев

Comment: вам знакомо && ?  я про этот кусок:

    if ($prop['spec_type_data'] === 'update_delete') {
        if (isset($prop['spec_type']['update'])) {

Comment: Конечно! Но если я все правильно понял вы предлагаете сделать так:  
if ($prop['spec_type_data'] === 'update_delete' && isset($prop['spec_type']['update'])) - я правильно понял? если да то в таком случае придется использовать еще один цикл в ['delete'] блоке

Comment: почему ? это же два условия вложенные друг в друга, без всяких промежуточных операций и ветвления второго условия. `if(cond1) {if (cond2) {do()}};` как изменение на `if (cond1 && cond2) {do()}` может повлиять на работу do() ? мало того я бы  cond2 и cond1 местами поменял.

Comment: Ааа...Теперь понял, большое спасибо, обязательно испробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// TODO: decomposition is needed
```

Инициализацию $data_my лучше вынести в отдельный метод и ни инициализировать каждый раз, а инициализировать, сохранить и, если опять его запрашивают, - возвращать сохраненный.

Сделать метод проверки текущего действия (вместо сравнивая в коде) и методы, выполняющие различный действия (удаление, обновление и т.д.)

```
// TODO: no diving (или как там погружения называются?)
```

Вместо погружения в условия лучше вызывать return, continue или break, смотря что требуется.

Используя ваш подход необходимо помнить где-что-как находится и обозначается. Заменив все на соответствующие методы вы уже будете читать код (алгоритм), а не названия параметров.

Убрав погружения код также читать станет легче. Согласитесь, что следующее намного проще читать:

```
public function select_deleteAll($type)
{
    $res_varchar = 0;
    $data = array();
    // $data_my = $this->getDataMy(); - будем вызывать там, где это понадобится
    if ($this->dataMyIsSmall($type); //, $data_my)) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->activateMessageBlock($data, $type);
    $ids = $this->input->post('ids');
    foreach ($ids as $id)
    {
        if ($id <= 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $this->deleteType($id); //, $data_my);
        $data['updated'] = true;
        if (!$this->isCycle($type)) { // $data_my))            {
            continue;
        }

        $propList = $this->getCycle($type); //$data_my);
        foreach ($propList as $prop)
        {
            $this->processPropAction($prop); //, $data_my);

             // В метод processPropAction вставить, например, следующее:

            //if ($this->isPropUpdate($prop))
            //{
            //    $this->updateProp($prop); //, $data_my);
            //    continue;
            //}

            //if ($this->isPropDelete($prop))
            //{
            //    $this->deleteProp($prop); //, $data_my);
            //    continue;
            //}

            //if ($this->isPropUpdateDelete($prop))
            //{
            //    $this->updateDeleteProp($prop); //, $data_my);
            //    continue;
            //}
        }
    }
}
$this->template->add_array($data);
$this->ajax_tpl('ajax');
}
```

Я бы и здесь немного подправил, но это - уже лучше чем у вас.

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз думал о том что бы сделать отдельную модель для этого, еще можно пару вопросов?

1)Например для пагинации я использую
$count = $this-db->get('table')->num_rows()

$this->db->limit($on_page, $page);
$this->db->get('table')->result();

Вопрос в след. правильно ли я делаю или можно как то обойтись одним запросом? например получить сразу все данные а потом выводить их из массива?

Comment: 2)Например я делаю галерею и на одной из спец. страниц мне надо вывести некоторые категории, я использую select multiple

Потом после отправки данных запускаю цикл который выдирает value
foreach ($select_arr as $sel)
{
   if ($sel != '')
   {
     $album_list .= $sel.',';
   }

}

и вставляю в базу
а для вывода делаю так:
$albums = explode(',', $albums_list);
array_pop($albums);
Это нормально? или есть другие более правильные способы?

Заранее благодарю